# Remainder operator gives negative result

Tags: java

I have a problem with remainder operator in java:
Why this:

```
(int)2147483648l % 10
```

gives a negative number (-8)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because `(int) 2147483648l` is `-2147483648`. You're casting the `long` to `int` and it is out of bounds.

Comment: `(int)` is a "to int" casting operator.

Comment: Now I found what's the problem. Initially I wanted to cast result to int, but should've done this: (int)(2147483648l % 10). And current example casts only left operand to int, not the result.

Comment: @dhblah Casting has a higher precedence than most other operators. When you see `()`, think high precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Casting problem .Data loss due to narrowing. You are converting long to int.

Read more about [conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html).

Answer (score 0):

From [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.17.3)

> The remainder operation for operands that are integers after binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) produces a result value such that `(a/b)*b+(a%b)` is equal to `a`.

from Narrowing Primitive Conversions [JLS 5.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#5.1.3)
So `2147483648l` will cast into int that will be `-2147483648`  and then based on `(a/b)*b+(a%b) = a`

Value should be `-8` what you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

use "long" in place of "int".
you can use it without typecasting also

Answer (score 0):

Following Example might be useful:

```
public class Example1
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int b = (int)2147483648l;
        System.out.println("Value of b: "+ b);
        System.out.println("Output1:  "+b % 10);

        long a = 2147483648l;
        System.out.println("Value of a: "+ a);
        System.out.println("Output2: "+ a % 10);
    }
}
```

**output**

```
Value of b: -2147483648
Output1:  -8
Value of a: 2147483648
Output2: 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a negative number because you're converting a `long` to an `int`. A possible work around in your case simply takes advantage of the fact that any decimal x mod 10 is simply the digit in the lowest decimal place (in the ones place). For example, 156 mod 10 is 6, because 156 divided by 10 is 15 + (6/10). So you could do something like this

```
//get the number and make it a string
String numberAsString = String.valueOf(number);

//get the integer value of the last character in the string (basically the lowest place)
int mod10 = Integer.parseInt(numberAsString.charAt(numberAsString.length() - 1));
```

This works for any integer `number` as long as what you want is `number % 10`